# Set Independent Default Print Settings for Different Users

Tags: windows-server-2019, network-printer, print-server, defaults

Problem: Our network deployed printers are set to default to print in black & white for cost savings. A few users want to print in color all the time, and are very annoyed at having to manually override the printer defaults every time.

Question: Is there a way to configure certain users with different default printing preferences (for color), while still forcing everyone else to use the print server defaults(B&W)?

Details: Sharp printers deployed via Server 2019 Print Services, all in the same building.

Comment: yup we did this also due the logo had a color that was interpreted as color, solution was to add the same printer with name printer sw and  printer color